# Can't install Nginx on Wheezy

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, apt

I'm trying to install nginx on wheezy using this code in my deployment script:

```
echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y nginx
```

However it doesn't seem that wheezy is supported by nginx yet. Can anyone tell me how I am meant to be installing nginx on wheezy please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't seem that wheezy is supported by nginx yet

What? There's a package in the main repository: [nginx (1.2.1-2.2)](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/nginx) . If you're having issues installing stuff nginx's repositories it's because they are not maintaining them properly or haven't updated them yet. If you go to their [dists](http://nginx.org/packages/debian/dists/) folder you'll notice they have not yet provided a package tree for wheezy.

Use the version of nginx included in the main repository or [build your own package](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=228570) from the latest stable release's source until nginx updates their repository.

Comment: This is the way to go if you don't need the current version of nginx and the old stable version shipped with Debian will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using the squeeze package which works fine - try that.

Comment: This is the way to go if you need the current version of nginx and the old stable version shipped with Debian won't work for you.